# How to optimize stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I would like to know if there are ways I could optimize n improve performance of this stored procedure. I'm fairly new at it & would appreciate your help.

This procedure I Inherited from the previous programmer.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDailyWorkConfB]    
    @datew DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    ;WITH tmpTable AS 
    (
        SELECT IdRealizare,Adresa, CONVERT(char(2), Data, 108) as Ora
        FROM Butoane
        WHERE (IdRealizare <> 0) AND (DAY(butoane.Data) = DAY(@datew)) AND (MONTH(butoane.Data) = MONTH(@datew)) AND (YEAR(butoane.Data) = YEAR(@datew)) 
    )

    SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS Qty INTO #tblOne
    FROM tmpTable
    GROUP BY IdRealizare,Adresa,Ora
    HAVING COUNT(*) >=1
    ORDER BY Ora

    SELECT Masini.Linie , Masini.CodMasina, Operatii.CodOperatie, Angajati.Angajat, Comenzi.NrComanda,Articole.Articol,
            OperatiiArticol.BucatiButon,Operatii.Operatie,OperatiiArticol.BucatiOra, Masini.Grup, #tblone.Ora, #tblOne.Qty, Realizari.Id, Operatii.PozRaport, Angajati.IdSector, Realizari.LastWrite,
            Articole.Stagione

    INTO #tblFOR
            FROM Realizari 
                        INNER JOIN Masini ON Realizari.IdMasina = Masini.Id 
                        INNER JOIN Angajati ON Realizari.IdAngajat = Angajati.Id
                        INNER JOIN Comenzi ON Realizari.IdComanda = Comenzi.Id 
                        INNER JOIN Operatii ON Realizari.IdOperatie = Operatii.Id
                        INNER JOIN Articole ON Comenzi.IdArticol = Articole.Id
                        INNER JOIN OperatiiArticol ON Comenzi.IdArticol = OperatiiArticol.IdArticol AND Operatii.id = OperatiiArticol.IdOperatie    
                        INNER JOIN #tblOne ON #tblOne.IdRealizare=Realizari.Id 

    SELECT * FROM #tblFOR WHERE Qty>0 AND IdSector='1' AND Linie in ('LINEA1','LINEA2','LINEA3','LINEA4','LINEA5','LINEA6','LINEA7','LINEA8','LINEA9','LINEA10','LINEA11','LINEA12') ORDER BY Realizari.Id 
 END
```

If some one have some idea I would like to hear that.
Thank you, best regards.

Answer (score 0):

One tip is that you should use WITH (NOLOCK) in your join query. Since this procedures basically build to show up the data So It is better that you may get uncommitted data rather than creating a deadlock when other queries performing update on those tables.